# How to create a java code for calculating the menu prices using if else and while loop

Tags: java

I need to create a code using java.
When any person enters this beverage shop, it shows how to select and order the menu items and quantity. After selecting one menu, code asks "Do you want to select another menu item". If you don't want another menu enter (-1). After entering (-1) price calculate through the code.The balance is over 1000/=  the shop gives 10% discount. The service charge(20%) and VAT(12%) must be added to the balance.

I have created a java code but it does not stop when user enter(-1) and I selected any one menu with one quantity, it shows the balance is 0.0
What is the error of my code.

```
 Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
  int i=0;
  double tot=0,price,vat,service,res=0,result;
 System.out.println("\t\t\t\tWELCOME TO BEVERAGE SHOP");
 System.out.print("User Name:");
 String name=scan.next();
 System.out.println("Hello!!!"+" "+name+" "+"Welcome...");
 System.out.print("\n");
 System.out.println("Please see our menu and select");
 System.out.print("\n");
 System.out.println("|\tPRODUCT ID\t|\t\tPRODUCT NAME\t\t|\tPRICE(LKR)\t|\n|\t1\t\t|\t\tTea\t\t\t|\t80\t\t|\n|\t2\t\t|\t\tCoffee\t\t\t|\t100\t\t|\n|\t3\t\t|\t\tIce Coffee\t\t|\t150\t\t|");
 System.out.print("\n");
 System.out.println("If you have selected the items you want,you can enter the product below");    
 while(i>=0){
     System.out.print("Product Id:");
     int id=scan.nextInt();
     System.out.print("Qyantity:");
     double quan=scan.nextDouble();

     System.out.println(id +":"+quan);

     System.out.print("if you want to stop entering id and buy, please enter \"(-1)\" \nor you want to continue enter anothe number:");
     int no=scan.nextInt();
     if(no==-1){
           vat=(res*12)/100;
           service=(res*20)/100;
           result=vat+service;
      System.out.println("Your Amount is:"+" "+result);
           if(res>1000){
           price=(res*10)/100;
           vat=(res*12)/100;
           service=(res*20)/100;
           result=(vat+service)-price;
           System.out.println("Your Amount is:"+" "+result);
           }
     }
     else{

         switch(id){
              case 1:
                  tot=80*quan;
                  break;
              case 2:
                  tot=100*quan;
                  break;
              case 3:
                  tot=150*quan;
                  break;   
       }
            res+=tot;  
     }  
 }
  i++;
```

}
}

Comment: of course it doesn't stop. your while depends on your i value, which you always augment

Comment: Then how should I stop the code when I enter -1

Comment: this is really bad code... whew...  int id=scan.nextInt(); -> after this you can check if it is -1. If so, break;

Comment: What is the purpose of using "i"?

Comment: @Phash unless -1 is a valid id

Comment: thats true... wait

Answer (score 0):

```
while(i>=0){
```

This line checks whether you'll continue or not. It only checks i.

```
i++;
```

this is the only line where I see you alter the value of i. Now, in order to get to that line, i has to be > 0.
Guess what (i+1) > 0 will return?

There's your endless loop.
You'll need to change

```
i++;
```

into `i= scan.nextInt();`
or check other variables.

Answer (score 0):

I will shorten this:

```
int no=scan.nextInt();
while(i>=0){
//your code
    int no=scan.nextInt();
    if(no==-1){
       //your code
       // leave the loop
       break;
    }

 }
```

you need for the exit / break condition and then leave the while - loop

Comment: now you are just changing functionality. What if it has to be possible to quit before the first execution? What if -1 is a valid value for id? Those are things you should consider before telling the OP to changing his code alltogether

Comment: you still have to keep in mind by changing the code as so, you are also changing the functionality.

Comment: it is checking for the explicit entry "no=scan.nextInt()" - this is no valid ID. I suggest putting the question for aborting on top of this...